# How to rotate pgfplots (NOT in `axis` subscription, but in `\addplot` itself) + `current axis.origin` error

Tags: pgfplots, errors

Uh, another thing I can't solve myself. I was toying around with `pgfplots`. I wanted to rotate a certain plot in the same axis as another plot (in `\addplot` environment and **not** in `\begin{axis}`). I went looking around and soon got a hold of `rotate around={<angle>:(current axis.origin)}` command. I added it to `[]` of my `\addplot` and at first it worked wonderful (no errors), but then (after I compiled my document about 5 times) the following error showed up:

```
Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable t
ick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} into 
your preamble.
on input line 9.


! Package pgf Error: No shape named current axis is known.
```

I took the `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}` suggestion, but nothing changed - still the same old error.

Oh, and here's a MWE. Note that the non-working parts are commented.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{external}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymin=-10,ymax=10, axis lines=center, axis equal]

\addplot[domain=-10:10, color=blue,samples=2000]{x^2};

%\addplot[domain=-10:10, color=red,samples=2000,anchor=origin,rotate around={-90:(current axis.origin)}]{x^2};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to know:

1. **how to resolve this error**
2. **how to effectively rotate plots in `\addplot` spectrum (and NOT `axis` subscription)**

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated comment: Having 2000 samples for a parabola like that is not really necessary, it only adds to the compilation time without making any visible difference to the plot. Something like 201 samples is sufficient with that domain.

Comment: I know, I know. I simply have a "fetish" that dictates the extreme overcomplication and unnecessary and absurdly powerful commands (OCD). Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead

```
\addplot[domain=-10:10, color=blue,samples=2000,
         transform canvas={rotate around={90:(0,0)}}]{x^2};
```

[image]